# Django: UpdateView restrict per user

Tags: django, django-generic-views, login-required

I have a site where users can create and edit their own lists.

I'm using the generic view CreateView to allow users to create lists.

I would like to use the generic view UpdateView to allow them to edit the lists, but the `login_required=True` is not enough in this case, since only the list creator can edit his/her list.

2 questions:

1) is there any parameter that I can specify in the URLconf to add this restrictions?

2) can I impose the those generic views should only work with POST and not GET?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could override `get_queryset` on the `UpdateView`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    base_qs = super(YourListUpdateView, self).get_queryset()
    return base_qs.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: I get **Page not found (404)** if it's not the user. I want another error saying Not Allowed for this user.

Answer (score 2):

1) you can write decorator and use it same way as `login_required` decorator, ie:

```
def user_permitted(function):
    def decorator(function):
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            # get obj from request
            if obj.user != request.user:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('forbidden'))
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator(function)
```

2) yes, see [decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/decorators/#allowed-http-methods) and [Decorating class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/#decorating-class-based-views)

Comment: **Decorators:** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/decorators/#allowed-http-methods and  **Decorating class-based views:** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views