# UpdateView and Preventing Users from Editing Other Users' Content

Tags: python, django

I'm using the UpdateView class to allow users to update their content in my app. I am now trying to figure out how to allow users to only edit their own content (and not other users' content). Appreciate any help.

```
class OrganismUpdate(UpdateView):
   model = Organism
   fields = ['name', 'edibility', 'ecosystem', 'weather', 'date', 'location']
   template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
   success_url ="/organism_images"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After narrowing down my question, I found an answer already on stackoverflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8595758/14263621

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `UserPassesTestMixin`class, so the user will only able to update hhis/heer profile

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin

class OrganismUpdate(UpdateView, UserPassesTestMixin):
   model = Organism
   fields = ['name', 'edibility', 'ecosystem', 'weather', 'date', 'location']
   template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
   success_url ="/organism_images"


    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.user= self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user== organism.user:
            return True
        return False
```